# Amazon custom AMI doesn't join to EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I would like to have custom AMI fro EKS, however I have got error with joining a node to cluster.

All initial steps passed without error. But a node hasn't joined to a k8s cluster. And I see the error `kubelet.go "Error getting node" err="node \"ip-10-0-31-89.ec2.internal\" not found"`

I use this Amazon EKS optimized Amazon Linux AMIs [ami-0baacf6d2f7060e93](https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/parameters/aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.22/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id/description?region=us-west-1) for Kubernetes version 1.22

My userdata are:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh '${cluster_name}' \
--b64-cluster-ca '${cluster_ca_certificate}' \
--apiserver-endpoint '${cluster_endpoint}' \
--use-max-pods=true \
--max-pods=20 \
--container-runtime containerd \
--ip-family ipv4 \
--kubelet-extra-args --node-labels=${karpenter_key}=${cluster_name},managed-by=karpenter
```

Comment: While this is blatantly off-topic for a programming stack exchange, I'll be helpful by letting you know it's caused by [the `system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}` rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html#aws-auth-configmap) getting blown away from your `kube-system/aws-auth` ConfigMap

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The rule is already present. It was a lack of "EKS created security group applied to ENI that is attached to EKS Control Plane master nodes, as well as any managed workloads."

Answer (score 0):

> sudo /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh '${cluster_name}' 
> ...

Use of **''** will not expand the variable you passed to the script. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${cluster_name} \
  --b64-cluster-ca ${cluster_ca_certificate} \
  --apiserver-endpoint ${cluster_endpoint} \
  --use-max-pods false \
  --container-runtime containerd \
  --ip-family ipv4 \
  --kubelet-extra-args "--node-labels=${karpenter_key}=${cluster_name},managed-by=karpenter --max-pods=20"
```

Create aws-auth [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html#aws-auth-configmap) if you only use self-managed node group.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the default security group wasn't attached to the node instance

**Default:** Cluster security group that was created by Amazon EKS for the cluster. Managed node groups use this security group for control-plane-to-data-plane communication. Referred to as 'Cluster security group' in the EKS console

Thanks all for your answers.